# Spring Boot Spel expression concatenate variables and convert them to lower case?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

Consider this method signature that I have

```java
@Cacheable(
  key="#name+'::'+#age+'::'+#country"
)
public User validate(String name, String age, String country) {
...
}
```

Notice the key that I have. Currently I am able to concatenate the name, age and country variables. But on top of concatenating them, I also want to convert the entire expression into a lowercase value.

For example if someone called this method like so: `validate("John","24","USA")`,

then I want my key to be resolved as: `john::24::usa`. Notice all the uppercase letters have become lowercase.

TLDR; how to write a spel expression which concatenates multiple variables and converts the entire result into lowercase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
Expression exp = new SpelExpressionParser()
    .parseExpression("(#foo + '::' + #bar).toLowerCase()");
StandardEvaluationContext ctx = new StandardEvaluationContext();
ctx.setVariable("foo", "XXX");
ctx.setVariable("bar", "YYY");
System.out.println(exp.getValue(ctx));
```

```
xxx::yyy
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. All I needed to do was wrap my spel around parenthesis and call toLowerCase method.